# Black border in all menus and black terminal after installing Katoolin

Tags: 16.04, katoolin, borders

I have this  problem with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
All programs and all menus have black boarders and Terminal is displayed black:

[image]

The problem appeared after installing [Katoolin](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin) tool and installing all Kali Tools.

Comment: There was another user yesterday who ran into a similar issue after installing the Kali Linux tools in Ubuntu.  Perhaps you could dual-boot Kali Linux instead, or run it in Virtualbox, since installing its tools in Ubuntu doesn't seem to work too well

Comment: so how can i fix ubuntu :/  
i don't want kali

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have this problem too, I think is due to adding Kali respiratory and updating your system, https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin on this page it gives you a clear warning not to update your system with Kali still in it. "Before updating your system , please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem." So just remove it, run an update restart and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by removing `xserver-xorg-video-intel`
using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Comment: This what solved it for me - thanks a lot for sharing, I had started to think about redoing the whole thing and thus to catch depression :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I'm not sure about the cause... I'm a beginner in these issues, but I just solved it with

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Man / Lady ! you saved my day....

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the following procedure. As the terminal was completely black and it was not possible to type the command in the terminal. Thus to enter the command, first press

ctrl+alt+F5

to go to the command line mode and then type the below mentioned command.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade