# Ubuntu 16:10 Black borders around windows and a blacked out terminal with no background : ANSWERED :

Tags: unity

[image]

Everything but my background, terminal and right click menu works. However, I'm unable to see the terminal, but it opens. This all started when I recently updated my Ubuntu.

I have attempted to reset unity & the theme back to normal, however this did not resolve my issue.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`
and `sudo apt-get install unity`

Comment: do i restart after this?

Comment: Yes `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: could this be caused by corrupt drivers because that didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone gets this problem in the future this is what worked for me

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Installing

what you have to do is to install MIR

Comment: Please expand upon what worked from that link. Since linked pages can change or disappear, someone who reads your answer won't know what you did to fix the problem. Also, if you have a second question about Steam, please don't ask it here. Instead, [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

On my ancient notebook with Intel graphics only, the problem got solved by removing the xserver-xorg-video-intel package as mentioned in another [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/887371) by user3458301 using the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Had this issue with an old Ubuntu 15.10 installation on a first Generation Intel Core-i notebook.